# Missing parameter type for expanded function in Scala ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala, sorting, types, parameters

While trying to run the following snippet from [Scala for the impatient](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774094):

```
val b = ArrayBuffer(1,7,2,9)
val bSorted = b.sorted(_ < _)
```

I get the following error:

```
 error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$less(x$2))
       val bSorted = b.sorted(_ < _)
```

Can somebody explain what might be going on here. Shouldn't the parameter type be inferred from the contents of the ArrayBuffer or do I need to specify it explicitly?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.sorted` takes an implicit parameter of type `Ordering` (similar to Java `Comparator`). For integers, the compiler will provide the correct instance for you:

```
scala> b.sorted
res0: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 7, 9)
```

If you want to pass a comparison function, use `sortWith`:

```
scala> b.sortWith( _ < _ )
res2: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 7, 9)

scala> b.sortWith( _ > _ )
res3: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(9, 7, 2, 1)
```

However, pay attention, although `ArrayBuffer` is mutable, both sort methods will return a copy which is sorted, but the original won't be touched.

Comment: So does this mean that the book has an error? Or did sorted take a comparison function at some point?

Comment: I think it's an error in the book. Perhaps a different Scala version ?

Comment: Not a different Scala version, no. Sorted was introduced from the start with that syntax -- iirc, up to 2.7.x it was `sort`, not `sorted`.

Comment: @sc_ray It's an error, and it's listed in [the errata](http://horstmann.com/scala/bugs.html).